# Error: An a start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, validation

My doctype is **html5**. I am validating this HTML:

```
<a class="article-link-block" href="http://localhost/article/231">

    <img src="http://localhost/images/article-image.jpg">

    <div class="article-info">
        <a class="title" href="http://localhost/article/231">Title of the article</a>
        <a class="category" href="http://localhost/category/5">Category</a>
        <div class="views">24x</div>
        <div class="date">13.3.2013</div>
    </div>

</a>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: An a start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.
```

I want the whole `div` to be an anchor tag ( **article-link-block** ) and within it another anchor tags to category, user etc. and other divs (the code above is simplified to only article and category link.)

How can I get rid of this error during html validation?

Comment: `div` tags are block level elements which aren't allowed to be inside inline elements like the `a` tag

Comment: So, how can that be "fixed"? I need to have divs there.

Comment: @iambriansreed [Yes they are allowed](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/)

Comment: You make think you need `div`s but a `span style="display: block"` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks @robertc. Perhaps you shouldn't include the `a` within the `a`. That type of construction will cause all kinds of neat things.

Comment: `Perhaps you shouldn't include the a within the a` I agree but I need the whole block to be clickable and only if something is different e.g. link to category or author, only then redirect to cattegory or author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it all to validate you're going to have to choose whether you want the block level link, or the child links.  You can't have both.  From [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

[Interactive content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#interactive-content) is:

> `a`    `audio` (if the `controls` attribute is present)    `button`    `details`    `embed`    `iframe`    `img` (if the `usemap` attribute is present)    `input` (if the `type` attribute is not in the Hidden state)    `keygen`    `label`    `object` (if the `usemap` attribute is present)    `select`    `textarea`    `video` (if the `controls` attribute is present)

So your options are:

1. Ignore the validator and keep it as it is (you have no right to expect all browsers to behave in the same way in this case)
2. Choose a different markup structure altogether
3. Replace either the block level or child links with normal elements and `click` events