# Creating url preview like facebook using css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create my own url preview. Like facebook shows. Dont want to use readymade script.

Here I go:
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/8wLMx/2/

```
  <div id="box" >

   <a href="" style="float:left; width: 300px; margin:0; margin-left:5px;" >some kind of title</a> <!--show url and title description-->
    <br/>
    <span> www.fbpreview.com <span>
        <br/>    
   <br />
   <div>
        <img src="'.$logo.'" height="84" width="66" style="float:left;"> <!--shows image on the page-->
        <p style="float:left; width: 300px; margin:0;">A lot of preview text A lot of preview textA lot of preview textA lot of preview textA lot of preview textA lot of preview textA lot of preview textA lot of preview text</p> 
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>
   <a href="" target="_blank" style="float:left; width: 300px; margin:0; margin-left:5px;" >See More</a> <!--See more link to go on that page--> 
</div>
```

Problem here is

```
1. Entire text is not getting floated on right side of image
2. Link should not be blue colored and underline
3. Box should be single clickable
```

Exactly same way as image preview shown by facebook when URL is entered.
In place of text area, I have text box.

I want to show same when url entered in text box.

Data will come from table. i.e. url, preview, image url, desc etc

Comment: This is almost the same as you asked yesterday, please search for it on google or something, because changing the style of an `a` like color and text-decoration are the basics of css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666534/fomating-content-like-url-preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/SykVM/

HTML:

```
<a class="fragment" href="google.com">
<img src ="http://placehold.it/116x116" alt="some description"/> 
<h3>quite the title we got here</h3>
<p class="text">
    this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etcthis is a short description yada yada peanuts etc 
</p>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.fragment {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.fragment img { 
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


.fragment h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #369;
}
```

Comment: sure thing, glad to be of help - there's one small mistake i've edited out: the closing tag should be </a> instead of </div>.

Comment: I just added the read more link which creates issue. P.S. http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/xftr5/1/

Comment: Placing anchors (<a> tags) within anchors will cause various errors, most noticeably the one where the browser 'extracts' it from the parent scope. since the entire box is one big link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566013/error-an-a-start-tag-seen-but-an-element-of-the-same-type-was-already-open
so instead, you can just use a span:
http://jsfiddle.net/xftr5/4/
also, note that repeating styles is something you want to avoid of - look at the h3,h4 mutual declaration.

Answer (score 2):

1. Entire text is not getting floated on right side of image
2. Link should not be blue colored and underline
3. Box should be single clickable

Number 1: The text is floating on the right side. 
Number 2: **Css:** `a{text-decoration:none; color:#000000;}` 
Number 3: To make the whole box clickable, you can put `<a>` tags around it.